# jQuery on change function issues

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Hello what i'm trying to do here is to make changes if value is selected and if not selected to hide but i want to do this with multiple values and same action.

The problem is when i try to do this just on one input file it works great but but i try to add multiple it not work.

Here is an jsFiddle example [`for this one`](http://jsfiddle.net/GY7dz/2/)

But when i try it with only one value it works.
I mean when i remove on line 17   -  ,'6'
and on line 24  -  ,'6' works perfect but i need to mess out with more selected values.

Any help will be appreciate.
Thanks

Comment: I suggest you stop what you're doing and spend some time on Code Academy: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript

Comment: You can't compare like `selection == '4','6'`. Hope [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GY7dz/3/) works for you.

Comment: Yeah, this one works now. What a great help.Thanks Satpal

Answer (score 0):

Bad Syntax:

```
if (selection !== '4','6') {
  rent.slideUp(200);
}
```

Correct implementation:

```
if (selection !== '4' && selection !== '6') {
  rent.slideUp(200);
}
```

And try not to use strings for numbers, generally. Go for this:

```
if (selection !== 4 && selection !== 6) {
  rent.slideUp(200);
}
```

Otherwise, good on the strict operator (!==).